# TRPC how to dynamically set context using server client

Tags: typescript, next.js, trpc

I'm following the [tRPC docs](https://trpc.io/docs/server/server-side-calls) on how to create a caller for server side calls but how are you suppose to set this value dynamically when used in your NextJS 13 pages?

This is what my context.ts looks like:

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import * as jose from "jose";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { inferAsyncReturnType } from "@trpc/server";

interface ContextUser {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    token: string;
}

export async function createContext() {
    async function getUserFromCookie(): Promise<ContextUser | null> {
        var token = cookies().get("jwt");

        if (!token?.value) return null;

        const secret = new TextEncoder().encode(process.env.JWT_SECRET);

        try {
            await jose.jwtVerify(token.value, secret);
        } catch (error) {
            return null;
        }

        const jwtPayload = jwt.decode(token.value) as any;

        return {
            id: jwtPayload.nameid,
            username: jwtPayload.unique_name,
            token: token.value,
        };
    }

    const user = await getUserFromCookie();

    return {
        user,
    };
}

export type Context = inferAsyncReturnType<typeof createContext>;
```

I have middleware to check that a user is set and I export a authorised procedure:

```
import { TRPCError, initTRPC } from "@trpc/server";
import { Context } from "./context";

const t = initTRPC.context<Context>().create();

export const router = t.router;
export const publicProcedure = t.procedure;

const authorised = t.middleware(async ({ ctx, next }) => {
    if (!ctx.user) throw new TRPCError({ code: "UNAUTHORIZED" });

    return next();
});

export const authorisedProcedure = t.procedure.use(authorised);
```

In my server.ts i'm exporting a server client like this:

```
import { appRouter } from "@/server";

export const trpcServerClient = appRouter.createCaller({
    user: { id: 1, username: "foo", token: "bar" },
});
```

When I call a procedure using the `trpcServerClient` with a valid cookie I can see by debugging the `createContext` that the token is present and it set the context, but in the procedure the `ctx` will be `user: { id: 1, username: "foo", token: "bar" }`.

My question then is how are you suppose to dynamically set the context when using a server client, when you have to pass a value for your context in the `createCaller` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { createContext } from "@/server/context"
import { appRouter } from "@/server";

export const trpcServerClient = appRouter.createCaller(await createContext());
```

(note that using await at top level may require changing your tsconfig target if you are still using "es5")

Comment: Does this mean you have to create a caller in every request if i need information like headers, or how does cookies() get resolved to the correct value otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

`createCaller` is deprecated in v11 or v12 of tRPC and here is the new approach to do this:

```
import { createContext } from "@server/context";
import { appRouter } from "@server/router";
import { t } from "@server/trpc";

const createCaller = t.createCallerFactory(appRouter);
export const serverClient = createCaller(await createContext());
```